# Where can I find the Windows Phone 7 GUI Standard?

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface

I'm looking for a GUI guideline, especially for Windows Phone 7. Does anybody know the name of it (it isn't AERO i think?). thank you!

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you inserted an image of Windows 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Latest User Experience Design Guidelines for Windows Phone can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 2):

> **Metro** is the name of the new design
>   language created for the Windows Phone
>   7 interface. ([source](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/windows-phone-7/metro/), my emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

[User Experience Design Guidelines for Windows Phone](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/8/6/D869941E-455D-4882-A6B8-0DBCAA6AF2D4/UI%20Design%20and%20Interaction%20Guide%20for%20Windows%20Phone%207%20Series.pdf)

Comment: @Tom Vervoort, an url shortner is not needed when you put it in an A-tag. Besides that, the .ly TLD is a not that quite stable domain to be used for long-term references to other sites.

Comment: Not confident that the [underlying link](https://bitly.com/d26CEL+) is much better :)

Comment: Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/publicsector/archive/2010/09/23/windows-phone-7-design-guidelines-now-available.aspx, didn't know the full link fast enough as it autodownloads (@jensgram, thanks, now I know how to find it)

Comment: and a -1 because it "WAS" a bit.ly, how low can you go ... Next Time I'm just not answerring